# Spring Integration: JDBC inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I was trying to use JDBC inbound channel adapter and I encountered some confusions.

First, which one is more efficient to use: specifying `max-rows-per-poll` or using `limit` on query statement? 
Second, to avoid the duplicate readings, is there anyway to run poller instead of `fixed-rate` after last message of each poll is processed? I could use `update` but there is dynamic update query down the stream.

My integration flow is somewhat like `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter -> http:outbound-channel-adapter -> jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter` (update each row as per response from `http:outbound-channel-adapter`). It should handle huge number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `LIMIT` is more efficient.
2. As long as you use `DirectChannel`s (the default), and no task executor on the poller, the next poll won't run until the current one completes, regardless of the trigger.

Comment: `the next poll won't run until the current one completes` does it mean next poll occurs only after the whole transaction of the that batch is complete?

Comment: Yes, as long as there's no async handoff to another thread; when the polling thread returns to the task scheduler, it consults the trigger to see when the next poll should happen, and schedules it; if the time has past, it will run immediately. So `fixed-rate` will only be accurate if the time to run the task is less than the rate itself.

Comment: The reason I am asking this is I have `http:outbound-channel-adapter` somewhere on the middle which might take some time to get the response. I guess that won't be problem then.

Comment: I assume you mean outbound-gateway; yes, by default, everything, including the gateway, will run on the poller thread. If you need to use multiple threads, you will need some other mechanism (an update) to prevent other threads from seeing the same rows.

Comment: My bad. Yes, I meant `outbound-gateway`. Thank you for the insights.